# Largest set of words that don’t share letters

Tags: english, letters

For instance,

> banana, excess, giggit, voodoo, pullup, myrrhy

are six six-letter words that don’t share any letters with each other. This isn’t a heterogram puzzle: repeated letters within a single word are fine. Can anyone find a larger set, or a set of longer words?

Full disclosure: this list may be used to cheat at Hangman. With this particular list, you can always claim that your opponent guessed wrong a minimum of five times in a row, though if you try this more than once on the same person they’ll probably make you write your word down somewhere first. Or just stop playing Hangman with you.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What's your definition of a "word"? Are proper nouns allowed? Are contractions, variant spellings, regional words, etc. allowed? Without a word list this question isn't really defined enough; could you provide a list/link of words considered acceptable?

Comment: Would a longer set of shorter words (eg, 7 three-letter words) be "better" than your example, or vice versa (four seven-letter words), or does it need to be better in both regards?

Comment: Probably 7 lettered six word or six lettered seven word would word.

Comment: Seems very open-ended: **giggit** and **pullup** (as a single word) are not in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/) or [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/).

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane. Need to define which dictionary to use for these type of puzzles

Comment: Technically, each individual letter appears with a dictionary entry, so the puzzle should probably have a minimum word length.

Comment: Does this fall under our "open-ended" policy? Puzzles that have no possible definitive answer (where any answer could be bested later) aren't allowed here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "Needs details or clarity" because without a single dictionary to work off of the definition of a "word" is unclear and opinion-based.

Answer (score 6):

My word list is a little looser, but all words can be found in the [Hasbro Scrabble Dictionary](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary).

9 four letter words:

> brrr*
>  cwms
>  deed
>  haha
>  juju
>  kook
>  lynx
>  pfft*
>  zizz*

I have * by words not found in Merriam-Webster. Also note that:

> haha isn't in Merriam-Webster, but ha-ha is, which is the word Scrabble is using.

Answer (score 5):

Here are seven five-letter words (all in Merriam-Webster)

> [crwth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crwth), [xylyl](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/xylyl), [kudzu](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kudzu), [igigi](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/igigi), [peeve](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peeve), [boffo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boffo), [amass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amass)

Comment: Wow, I was going scrabble, so this is certainly better, although I'm hoping for 9

Answer (score 5):

Six 7-letter

> boombox hallway prepped tsktsks unungun vivific

Five 8-letter

> agaragar infinity levelled poohpooh succumbs

Four 9-letter

> highlight knockdown queuejump sassafras

Four 10-letter

> chachalaca divinizing pussyfoots rememberer

Not always in the "right" dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this works...

> This is four letter words: myth, gull, reef, book, jinx, ppap, wdwd.

Comment: I may delete it anytime is this can’t work.

Comment: Whether your last two "words" work depend on how the OP defines "word"

Answer (score 2):

There are 9 words in this set of 3-letter words. I used the [Merriam Webster Scrabble Dictionary](https://scrabble.merriam.com/finder/zzz).

> zzz
>  tsk
>  pop
>  nun
>  myc
>  grr
>  ewe
>  bib
>  aah

Comment: Note that rot13 "ol erzbivat zlp naq ercynpvat vg jvgu zzz naq syl, lbh pna trg 10 jbeqf"

Comment: 10 is optimal for 3-letter words in that dictionary: aah bee coo did fly grr mmm nun pst zzz

Answer (score 1):

8 2-letter words from the Scrabble dictionary:

> aa
>  mm
>  sh
>  qi
>  ex
>  ow
>  by
>  nu

There's some flexibility in which 2-letter words you use, so you could steal some longer words from other answers that don't use vowels to get a larger set.

I have to imagine that if you started off a hangman game with `_ _` your opponent would be quite upset!

Comment: I confirm that 8 is optimal for 2-letter words in that dictionary.

Comment: This is getting to much... two letters are just too easy...